# Why is the exponent when working in $L^p$ spaces often dropped?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Formally, a function belong $L^p$ if $[\int |f|^p d\mu]^{1/p} < \infty$, but it seems quite common in proofs to drop the exponent? Why?

Comment: If $x \in [0,\infty]$ do you see any difference between $x<\infty$ and $x^{1/p} <\infty$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe you have a typo, but I assume you are saying if the integrand is finite then so is the whole expression, but then why is the exponent in the definition to begin with?

Comment: We use $(.)^{1/p}$ to get a norm. Triangle inequality requires this power. $\int |f+g|^{p} \leq \int|f|^{p}+\int|g|^{p}$ is not true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah I see so it's merely there to obtain a norm, otherwise we may just concern ourselves with the expression without the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

In pure math, usually we don't care about the exact value of a non-negative real number. Rather, we care about its "categories'':

- it is zero
- it can be arbitrarily small
- it is a constant
- it can be arbitrarily large
- it is $\infty$

If we drop the exponent, then the math expression is simplified while these "categories'' are still preserved. On the other hand, if we care about the exact value (e.g. for proving a tight inequality), then the exponent may need to be kept, because it serves as a normalization. E.g. Consider the difference between variance and standard deviation in probability theory.

Comment: A nonnegative real number cannot be "arbitrarily small", "arbitrarily large" or infinity.

Comment: ... and 'zero' is also a constant ;)